How to catch Laravel Sanctum MissingAbilityException, and access the associated missing ability?
I'm working on a Laravel 11 app, and using the API tokens functionality of Sanctum (no SPA, no session, no CSRF etc, REST API and tokens, routes in api.php not web.php).  All is working well - I can issue tokens and use them to access routes protected by auth:sanctum middleware.  I'm now adding abilities to the tokens, and using the abilities middleware to control access to some routes.
I've added the required middleware aliases in bootstrap/app.php:
$middleware->alias([
    ...
    'abilities' => \Laravel\Sanctum\Http\Middleware\CheckAbilities::class,
    'ability' => \Laravel\Sanctum\Http\Middleware\CheckForAnyAbility::class,
]);

And added an abilities check in a route in routes/api.php:
Route::middleware(['auth:sanctum', 'abilities:foo'])->group(function () {
    Route::get('/foo', [FooController::class, 'foo']);
});

Now I generate a token without any abilities:
$token_without_abilities = $user->createToken('name', [], Carbon::now()->addMinutes(10))->plainTextToken;

When I try to access the /foo route described above, using that token which does not include the required foo ability, I expect it to fail, and sure enough an exception is thrown.  According to the source, in \Laravel\Sanctum\Http\Middleware\CheckAbilities, MissingAbilityException should be thrown.  I added some debug logging and verified that indeed is what seems to be happening, I reach the constructor of MissingAbilityException, and I am able to log the missing ability as $ability at that point.
I want to catch that exception and return a JSON response with the right error msg, so I added the following in my bootstrap/app.php:
use Laravel\Sanctum\Exceptions\MissingAbilityException;

->withExceptions(function (Exceptions $exceptions) {
    $exceptions->render(function (MissingAbilityException $exception, Request $request) {
        Log::debug('MissingAbilityException exception: ' . printr_r($exception->abilities(), true);

        return response()->json([
            'message' => 'Missing ability ' . $exception->getMessage(),
        ]);
    });
});

But the exception is not caught, instead a AccessDeniedHttpException is thrown, and I end up with:
{
    "message": "Invalid ability provided.",
    "exception": "Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\Exception\\AccessDeniedHttpException",
    "file": "/var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Exceptions/Handler.php",
    "line": 633,
    "trace": [
        {
            "file": "/var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Exceptions/Handler.php",
            "line": 577,
            "function": "prepareException",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Exceptions\\Handler",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php",
            "line": 51,
            "function": "render",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Exceptions\\Handler",
            "type": "->"
        },
... 

Edit: linked to wrong stack trace, fixed.  Full stack trace.
The only hint I can find about this is this answer to a Github issue asking more or less the same as me.  That answer suggests what I'm already doing, AFAICT, though in pre-Laravel 11 syntax.
If I try to catch AccessDeniedHttpException in bootstrap/app.php the same way, it does work, but I can't seem to access the missing ability any more, $exception->abilities(); gives me a Call to undefined method.
How can I catch a MissingAbilityException and access the actual missing ability?  The goal is to return a JSON response to the client with a message like You don't have the "foo" permission.

the MissingAbilityException is passed to the AccessDeniedHttpException, this one is inherits from some other Exception classes and more importantly from the RuntimeException class. The MissingAbilityException is passed up all the levels until it reaches the RuntimeException and you can (should, as i have not tested myself) access it with the getPrevious() method.
So you would still catch the AccessDeniedHttpException $e, but you can access the MissingAbilityException by doing $e->getPrevious();

Thanks, this works.  Why does the MissingAbilityException not appear in the stack trace?

i cant access the stack trace page anymore, if you make it again i ll check

Sorry - I've added it again: https://pastebin.com/WcSMvT0V

the AccountManagementMiddleware.php should be the file throwing the exception (line 29), the exception is caught in the pipeline and the handleException called, when the render methods is called the MissingAbilityException is 'mapped' into the AccessDeniedHttpException which is returned as a response

Sorry, I see I've given the wrong stack trace, I tried to replicate the error by commenting out the getPrevious() fix but I've changed other code since then so this is a different exception.  I've updated it again (https://pastebin.com/nCFE6v1j), but I think the mapping part you describe is the key, how does that happen?

just look at the render method in the foundation/exception/handler class, the prepareException receives the original exception, which is mapped to an AccessDeniedException which is just rendered to a response
